# How do I implement a pure Python Pillow image plugin?

Tags: python, plugins, encoding, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write an encoder for a special image format. My intention is to implement it in *pure* Python as an image plugin for Pillow.

There is an entry in its docs ([Writing Your Own Image Plugin](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/writing-your-own-file-decoder.html)) that gives some hints as to how to implement the decoder. With that and some help I got at the project's issues section I managed to get a decoder working.

However, all their encoders are written in C and the `ImageFile.PyEncoder` superclass (from which all Python encoder classes should inherit) is not even implemented. The documentation is also very sparse in this respect.

Given this state of affairs, is it possible to get such an encoder working? If so, I'd like to know what methods to write, where to get the image data from and where to write the encoded result to.

Related issues:

- [Writing your own image plugin documentation missing information](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4818);
- [PyEncoder doesn't exist](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4059)

Edit 1: I'm not looking for a detailed encoder implementation. It's just that the docs don't state what the structure should be in Python. If it serves as proof of work, here is a [repo](https://github.com/Piolie/DjvuRleImagePlugin) with my work so far.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.

Comment: @Prune To me it seems that the poster is just searching for some missing documentation for pillow and maybe a workaround for the missing implementation of PyEncoder.

Comment: @Prune I did read the intro. I'm asking first if the problem is solvable in Python. Then just some hints as to what the structure of the class should be, given the lack of documentation. Directions to some other encoder already implemented would be enough. Please see my edit.

Comment: @MichaelButscher either of which is supposed to be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get an encoder working by manually implementing the encoder class. The required public methods are:

- `__init__`: sets `self.mode` and gets the parameters for the encoder, if any;
- `(@property) pushes_fd`: simply `return self._pushes_fd`;
- `setimage`: sets `self.im` (the Pillow image object) and gets the image size;
- `setfd`: sets `self.fd` (the file object to write to);
- `encode_to_pyfd`: this is the method that you have to write. Read your input data from `self.im`* and write it to `self.fd`;
- `cleanup`: perform decoder specific cleanup (just `pass` works).

The class also needs to set `_pushes_fd = True`.

Though a bit of a kludge, it was easier than I expected.

*I found it better to work with `list[self.im]` instead of `self.im` directly. The former allows slicing and all other list operations.

Comment: As of Feb 2022, this is officially being addressed at [PR#6069](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/6069).